# Bootstrap: Make a buttons width 33% and when the window is too small 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three buttons and I want them to be on the same line, take all the space and every button has to be the same size.
And as soon as the window is too small to show every button at at least 170px width, I want every button to have their own line and take 100% of it.
I remember seeing websites that have navigation bars which work somewhat like this..

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
        <div class="modal-body"> 
          <button style="min-width:33%;width:170px" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-group">Button A</button><span></span>
          <button style="min-width:33%;width:170px" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-group">Button B</button><span></span>
          <button style="min-width:33%;width:170px" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-group">Button C</button>
        </div>
```

The first part seems to work fine, but when the window gets too small, the buttons don't take 100% width on their line:

[image]

Is there a bootstrap way to achieve that? Or is a css hack necessary?

Answer (score 3):

I would rewrite the HTML to look like this.

```
<div class="modal-body"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
            <button style="width:100%" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-group">Button A</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4  col-sm-12">
            <button style="width:100%" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-group">Button A</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4  col-sm-12">
            <button style="width:100%" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-group">Button A</button>
        </div>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like the right direction, but now the window needs to be extremely wide before the buttons are displayed on the same line: http://i.snag.gy/Ggb5F.jpg

Comment: Replace "col-lg-4 col-sm-12" with "col-xs-12 col-sm-4" or "col-xs-12 col-md-4" depending on which device size you want the change to occur.

Comment: That is better, but not still not the 170px per button I asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a media query to css

```
button{
    width: 170px
}
@media (max-width: 540px){
     button{
         width: 100%;
     }
}
```

For best results add a parent class to button

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Bootstrap then you should be able to use the 'col' CSS selector

you should be able to apply a container (or row) class depending how much of the screen you want to fill, then apply 'col-md-4 col-sm-12' (depending on the breakpoint you want it to go 100%) to all the buttons you shouldn't write the CSS inline like the example above use the bootstrap classes...

link to the bootstrap documentation http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: What exactly do the values in `col-md-4 col-sm-12` do? Do you have a link to that part of the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Bootstrap grid system documentation to understand more about Col settings on different sizes.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid